# Using pypika to generate SQL Server query with an "OUTPUT" clause

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, pypika

I am using pypika to build queries that will be sent to SQL Server. SQL Server has an [`OUTPUT` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) that I would like to include in the query to return the uniqueidentifier that will be generated by default on an `INSERT`. pypika does not have any built-in functionality for adding an `OUTPUT` clause to the query.

Is there any way to generate a query containing an `OUTPUT` clause with pypika?

Example of the type of query I am trying to generate:

```
INSERT INTO Table (Name, Email) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id, INSERTED.Name, INSERTED.Email 
VALUES ('name', 'email');
```

edit: fixed example query syntax

Comment: `values ("name", "email")` with double quotes is incorrect syntax on SQL Server. You will get `Invalid column name 'name'` and `Invalid column name 'email'` errors. Try instead `values ('name', 'email')` with single quotes.

Comment: We don't have an implementation for that. Best is to make a ticket on our Github for that OUTPUT clause to be added to the SQL Server dialect. You can also submit a pull request with the dialect functionality, which we would be more than happy to merge in. The implementation of it shouldn't be too complex I believe.

Comment: @GlennD.J. thanks for letting me know. happy to look into implementing the functionality myself